# Entity table is not displaying in the EF 3.5 Model as table has only foreign key reference columns

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am using EF 3.5 and have created the table name CustomerEULAAcceptance with two columns who has foreign key reference but not able to see on the EF side entities.

Please help me...

Comment: EF displayes only those tables who has primary key or composite primary keys... need to check for foreign key ref.

Comment: I have also added one more column with primary key but still getting an error : " Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 4383:Must specify mapping for all key properties (CustomerEULAAcceptance.EulaAcceptanceId) of table CustomerEULAAcceptance. 
"

Comment: Drag another table which keys used as ref. in u r table